# adding video on android app using delphi firemonkey

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I have been looking everywhere for help for below task :

Whats the easy way to add a video file and just on button click play the video on a android device. Everytime when it run the code, and when i press the button it shows black screen and then it closes .

Here is my code :

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
mediaplayer1.FileName :=  'c:\sapoavi2.avi';
if MediaPlayer1.Media <> nil then
begin
  MediaPlayer1.Play;
end;
```

Also, i have a mediaplayercontrol box to display the video.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: There is not c:\ path on Android. You have to provide proper video filename.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is wrong, as per [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Audio-Video_in_FireMonkey)

> Video on Android Platform
>    ...  Android video files are typically the
>   H.263 format. For more information, see
>   http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

You should first take a look at [the mobile code snippets](https://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/branches/RADStudio_Seattle/Object%20Pascal/Mobile%20Snippets/VideoPlayback/)

Comment: thank you for the information . i download a proper video file to test and i remove the directory to MediaPlayer1.FileName := 'Kayaking.mp4';  and i place the video in the folder studio\project but still do the same it do not play the video . or if you can please tell me how to do it please thank you